# How to rewrite theme path with difference in folder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having trouble with .htaccess config...

List files and folders content:

```
/
    src/
        css/
            admin/styles.css
            user/styles.css
        js/
            admin/init.js
            user/init.js
```

I want to access the file/folder path will matching paths rewrite

```
http://domain/src/css/staff/styles.css => src/css/admin/styles.css
http://domain/src/css/styles.css => src/css/user/styles.css

http://domain/src/js/staff/styles.js => src/js/admin/init.js
http://domain/src/js/styles.js => src/js/user/init.js
```

And here is my code:

```
RewriteRule ^src/staff/(.*)$ src/admin/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^src/(.*)$ src/user/$1 [L]
```

But apparently things not working, there was an error has occurred "500 Internal Server Error".

If you just take a look at my problem and share a bit of your science, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more regex matching you can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(src)/(js|css)/staff/([^/.])+\.(css|js)$ $1/$2/admin/$3.$4 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(src)/(js|css)/([^/.])+\.(css|js)$ $1/$2/user/$3.$4 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Exactly what I need!
But, I need to modify the code `([^/.])+` to `([^/.]+)` for within filenames are more characters...
Thanks!